# Using Plymouth on ArchLinux

Tags: linux, boot, archlinux

I have installed Plymouth on ArchLinux. And have done everything according the documentation. The problem is that the displayed splash, is not the theme I have set, In fact I couldn't find it in any of the themes in /usr/share/plymouth/themes! A gray screen is shown, with three white squares that toggle on and off one after each other. I can guess that this is a fallback theme, but I have set the default theme. What is the problem? Any hint is appreciated. I am using grub2 as bootloader.

Comment: From the archwiki: "Warning: Plymouth is currently under heavy development and may contain serious bugs." If you did everything correctly, reverse your changes and wait for a more stable version or look for an other alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I had guessed this was a fallback theme. And as no one gave me a better answer all this while, I give my solution for this problem. It seems like something was broken in the changes that I had made, and I think it was in plymouth's own created files and not the config files. I uninstalled the plymouth, then deleted all the configuration files in the etc folder, and then reinstalled it again. All the files that I had deleted were created again, and everything was working. This time when I applied the modification things got working this time.